# Snide and unprofessional remarks from senior employee

Tags: work-environment, human-resources, unprofessional-behavior

I have come across a situation where an employee more senior than I (I am 30 and he is probably in his 50's or 60's) has taken a habit of making deprecating comments towards me such as the following. Please note that I am an immigrant under a working visa from a developing country, and the senior employee is a native of the developed European country where I currently work. Let's say I come from Kazakhstan:

- "kazakhs are barbarians"
- "Your goal is to work here and then run off to kazakhstan so you can collect welfare money, right?
- "Do as you're told, Boy."

The senior employee has a lot of international experience in developing countries, speaks kazakh, and so probably thinks that they are being light-hearted. At first I took things lightly and didn't think much of it, but the repeated and increasing aggressivity of the comments has begun to take its toll.

I called this person earlier today and proposed that we go grab a coffee. I thought I would inform them in person that I don't find these interactions funny or amusing anymore. However this employee is a senior, has very little time, and probably sees the trap laid out before them. They did not take my request to grab a coffee seriously, diffused it and probably will not address it again.

I decided the next best thing is an email, so I wrote something along the lines of :

> Dear Senior Employee,
>
> It appears that both our schedules are too busy for us to have a one
>   on one coffee like I proposed earlier today. This unfortunately leaves
>   me no choice but to write an email.
>
> The reason I wanted to talk is as follows: I wanted to inform you that
>   I have reached a point where our day to day interactions make me
>   uncomfortable. I am referring to both general comments and specific
>   ones related to, (for example) my ethnic and cultural background.
>
> While your intention may not necessarily be to offend, I would like to
>   inform you that I perceive things differently. I find most of these
>   comments highly offensive and inappropriate. Would it be possible for
>   you to take this into consideration in our future interactions?
>
> I  hope that this message will not jeopardize our working relationship
>   and I look forward to working together on future projects. Please do let
>   me know if you would like to further discuss in person and I would be
>   happy to do so.
>
> Best Regards,

I want to give this person the benefit of the doubt. If this email doesn't have the desired effect (i.e. for them to completely stop all snide comments and limit interactions to things related to work). I thought I would collect all incidents in writing and stop by HR.

Would you guys please let me know if this is a reasonable approach? Does my email have a reasonable tone? Do I run any risks by making such a complaint in writing? I would like to eliminate this source of toxicity in my workday.

**EDIT**

Some problems I see with this approach is:
 - the employee could decide to ignore the email and persist with the behavior, and claim to never have been made aware if I ever end up going to HR
 - the employee may actually miss the email
 - the employee may read and acknowledge the email but not respond.

Comment: To address your edit: The employee can "claim" to have missed the email, but cannot steer clear of the fact that you communicated the problem to them. They missed the email - that's again a problem from their side, you'll have enough proof to show that you initiated the communication.

Comment: If you vote for the question to be closed would you please indicate why?

Comment: not you @SouravGhosh. I was saying in general...

Comment: They are actually pretty close, unfortunately. They are however delivered in a joking tone. It is true that among "Kazakhs", for instance we will self-deprecate and use such language, but amongst each other it doesn't sound as offensive. Kind of like black people in the US find it OK to call each other the N word but highly offensive if a white person uses it. This person, since they speak my language and lived in countries similar to my own, thinks that they are entitled to these kind of comments... Except they are white-european, and I have never granted them permission...

Comment: Offensive language is offensive no matter what race you are.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think that's strictly true; whether certain language offends or not can depend on cultural characteristics, such as race, age, etc. However, in this case I think we can all agree that the coworker is out of line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I think you did the right thing. The language and tone of the email conveys the message in a perfect way, you can send it.

Wait for the outcome. If the email do not change the situation, go to HR. The first two comments and likes are harassment and discrimination - most likely it will not be tolerated in any sensible workplace.

Comment: didn't send the email yet. Wanted to run it by you guys first to see if its appropriate...

Comment: @user32882 I'm in for the idea, send it.

Comment: Will wait to see if other people have different answers. Would like to get some perspective on this.... though I of course agree with you

Comment: @user32882 Of course, I did not mean to rush you. All I'm saying is - you're thinking the correct way.

Comment: @user32882 Agreed with Sourav - you're approaching it the right way, and HR will likely ask you if you've tried to resolve this directly with the employee anyway.

Comment: I think what I might do is first go down to HR, tell them about it but not disclose the name of the person. Then I will show them the email to see if they are OK with it. If they are (and they better be) I will send it. Is that a good plan?